# How to interrupt Python background daemon with Ctrl+C equivalent (forcing KeyboardInterrupt exception)

Tags: python-2.7, background-process, daemon, keyboardinterrupt

I have a Python daemon that monitors machine performance during the execution of another software. It basically retrieves data of target processes with `ps` and writes it to a CSV file to be plotted when the daemon is stopped.

If the daemon is running in a terminal as a foreground process, the user can stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, what will force a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. I capture that exception and plot the content of the CSVs then.

The problem comes when I have to launch the daemon in a background process with `nohup myDaemon.py &`. It works fine, as it generates the CSVs, but as I can't force a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception the CSVs are not automatically plotted if I kill or stop the background process with other methods than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

What I want to avoid is having to move the plotting part to a separate script and run it manually after stopping the daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer reading `kill` man page. It turns out that signal -2 (SIGINT) is the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Tested it running `kill -2 <Background_Daemon_PID>` and worked just fine.